# what is the best way to match a version number from file

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep, regular-expression, perl

what is the best way to match specific version number ( or version number ) from file

I did some options , but I think there are other best approach ( as perl one-liner )

```
   version=23.092.12
   cat generic_version | grep  "$version"
   cat generic_version | grep -F "$version"
   cat generic_version | awk -v ver=$version '/ver/'
```

**generic_version**  - is a file with a lot of float versions

example

```
cat /tmp/generic_version | ......
```

expected results:

```
23.092.12 # version approve
```

example of file

```
23.087.23  # version approve 
23.092.12  # version approve 
23.098.45  # version approve 
23.099.12  # version under testing
```

Comment: As far as I know you cannot call `23.092.12` float number.

Comment: ok but I not find other name so we call it version number

Comment: As all questions about "best": Please qualify what the sorting criteria is: Shortness of the command, shortest execution time, unreadability of the command, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, you'd want to match on `$version` provided  it's not preceded nor followed by a digit or dot to avoid matching on things like 23.092.123 or 1.23.092.12 (though you may also want to also consider cases like `23.092.12-rc1`, `23.092.12b`, `23.092.12-2`...). May be easier with `perl`:

```
<generic_version V=$version perl -ne 'print if m{(?<![\d.])\Q$ENV{V}\E(?![\d.])}'
```

That matches on:

```
xxx 23.092.12 yyy
xxx23.092.12yyy
23.092.12-pre1
```

But not on

```
23.092.12.2
23.092.123
123.092.12
23.092.12.
```

The `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are respectively negative look behind and look forward regex operators. We use `\Q...\E` so that the content of the env var is taken as a fixed string instead of a regexp (so `.` loses its special meaning of matching any character).

If, as per your edit, your version numbers in the input file are always found at the start of the line and always followed by a spacing character, you can simplify it to:

```
<generic_version V=$version perl -ne 'print if m{^\Q$ENV{V}\E\s}'
```

Or use `awk` to match on lines whose first field is the version:

```
<generic_version V=$version awk '$1 "" == ENVIRON["V"]'
```

The concatenation with `""` is to force a string comparison. Without it, with a `$version` like `123.4`, it would match on `123.40`.

To match on the `$version` being any space delimited field in the input:

```
<generic_version V=$version perl -ne 'print if m{(?<!\S)^\Q$ENV{V}\E(?!\S)}'
```

That is `$version` provided that it's neither preceded nor followed by a non-spacing character (`\S`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the file `generic_version` contains a version number per line and that `$version` may match one of these lines exactly:

```
grep -xF "$version" generic_version
```

The `-F` flag causes `grep` to interpret the pattern as a fixed string rather than as a regular expression, while `-x` forces the match to span the whole line (as if `^` and `$` had been used in a regular expression pattern).

---

After revealing the format of the file in the question:

```
awk -v v="$version" '$1 == v' generic_version
```

This will output every line of the file whose first whitespace separated column is identical to the value of the `version` variable.

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution (according to your input file format):

```
version="23.092.12"
awk -v ver="$version" '$1 == ver' /tmp/generic_version
```

The output:

```
23.092.12  # version approve
```